Are flap track fairings (just the appendages themselves) necessary for wing aerodynamics?
Coming from this answer by Peter Kämpf leaving me a little perplexed about the necessity of flap track fairings. without flap tracks, would we still need them on the wing of any given sub/transonic aircraft?

"without flap tracks, would we still need them on the wing", it's not clear what is "them", do you mean: Are flap track fairings required for sub/transonic aircraft?

@mins sorry, "them" was referring to the fairings.

This might also help.

No.  The use of flap track fairings as a way of influencing transonic aerodynamics is called Kuchemann Carrots.  Because they kinda look like Carrots and they were proposed by Dietrich Kuchemann.
A modern clean wing (without the antishock bodies) could be designed using a different airfoil and perhaps different planform.
Of course, modern clean wings do need flap tracks (to hold the flap deployment mechanisms and structure) and so some characteristics of this sort of design still persists.  You want to make the flap tracks as small as possible -- but then shape them to interact as favorably as possible.

You do your best to incorporate the tracks into the airfoil profile so as little as possible is sticking into the airstream when they are retracted. To the extent you can't do that and you have bits protruding, you fair the tracks like any appendage or mechanism sticking out into the airstream and adding parasite drag.
You may elect to do this and live with fairings (sometimes called "canoe fairings" on airplanes with long-travel Fowler flaps whose tracks project below the trailing edge) because structural or mechanical design priorities make it worthwhile
